# Why does adding a canvas element overlfow the width of the enclosing div?

Tags: css, html, canvas

I have the following HTML with a canvas embedded in a fieldset.  Why does the fieldset and canvas with overflow the enclosing div dimensions?   I basically want the fieldset and canvas to reside within the dimensions of the enclosing div.  If I remove the "canvas" element, then it sizes properly.  What am I not understanding here/

```
<body>
  <div id="commandGrp" style="position:relative;float:left;width:100px;height:100px">
     <fieldset><legend>Commands</legend>
        <canvas id="CommandCanvas" >

        </canvas>
     </fieldset>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is a screenshot with the Chrome element inspector so you can see the div size.  You can see the div#commandGrp div is the size I defined it but the enclosing fieldset and canvas are way bigger.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's down to the HTML specification and default sizes on `canvas`. See this similar Stack Overflow question for links and solutions.

[canvas default size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792788/canvas-default-size)