# Canvas arrow is not shown in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I have drawn an arrow in canvas using the below code.

```
  window.onload = function() {
    var canvas   = document.getElementById("arrow");
    var context  = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle  = "red";
    context.fillStyle    = "red";

    context.moveTo(150, 400);
    context.lineTo(400, 400);
    context.lineTo(375, 375);
    context.arcTo(400, 400, 375, 425, 35);

    context.lineTo(400, 400);
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
  });
```

But the arrow is not shown on the screen.

Comment: Did you set the `width` and `height` attributes of the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

In the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-author-20120329/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element), the canvas element has a default coordinate size of 300×150px.

If you use CSS to resize the canvas to, say, 500×500px, then the canvas coordinates will be stretched so that (300, 150) is still the bottom right of the canvas: http://jsfiddle.net/Mh4uH/

You need to also apply a canvas `width` and `height` property:

```
<canvas id="arrow" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to set the width and height to match the on-screen dimensions (http://jsfiddle.net/Mh4uH/1/):

```
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
```

See also: [canvas default size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792788/canvas-default-size)