# Javascript Canvas Drawing moves out of canvas after translate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, translate

I am having a problem with randomising rectangle locations on the screen. I have a 5 x 5 grid set up with  in html and they are all formatted properly. I am then drawing bars into this grid which also works fine. The problem is that when I want to randomly jitter these objects they sometimes move off the canvas (to the left, or to the top only) apparently. I am trying to reposition the canvas via jQuery with no success.

Also, I have the feeling my canvas sizes are wrong but if I set the sizes to 100% in the CSS section, the bars are suddenly very small and I have no idea why.

Here is the interesting piece of the code. the problem is the "jitter" part

```
function drawStimulus(size, color, orientation, location){  

// size for each box, refers to the first box in the first row
// box size should be around 40 on a 22inch screen in this jsfiddle
var box_size = $("#testbox").height();

var stimulus_size = box_size * size; // size is either 1 (large) or 2/3    
var size_diff = box_size-stimulus_size;
var c = document.getElementById(location);

c.width = box_size;
c.height = box_size;

// if a perfect grid is not wanted, jitter bars randomly
// by a maximum of 1/3 of the box size in any direction
if(jitter){
  var hjitter = rand(-box_size/3, box_size/3);
  var vjitter = rand(-box_size/3, box_size/3);
  c.style.left = String(c.style.left+hjitter)+"px";
  c.style.top = String(c.style.top+vjitter)+"px";  
}

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
// rotate around center
ctx.translate(box_size/2, box_size/2);
ctx.rotate(orientation*Math.PI / 180);
ctx.translate(-box_size/2, -box_size/2);

// draw bars
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = color;
ctx.moveTo(c.offsetLeft+size_diff/2,c.offsetTop+box_size/2);
ctx.lineTo(c.offsetLeft+stimulus_size+size_diff/2,c.offsetTop+box_size/2);
ctx.lineWidth = size*10;
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
}
```

Here is also a jsfiddle with the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/msauter/pdrwwm7x/

Comment: I didn't have time to test your code, but the "bars are suddenly very small" are due to the fact that the canvas size are not specified and uses the default value. When you "set the sizes to 100% in the CSS section" the resulting image is re sampled.

Comment: It most likely exits the visible area due to how the arguments to `translate` are not related to the actual canvas size (CSS size has no effect on that, your sample is using the default size http://stackoverflow.com/a/12019582/783219), I also will try change to `trans...(-...); rot...(...); trans...(...);".

Comment: Thanks for answering. I used

    `c.width = box_size;
    c.height = box_size;`

to set the canvas size and repositioned it via 

     `c.style.left = String(c.style.left+hjitter)+"px";
     c.style.top = String(c.style.top+vjitter)+"px";`

the canvas seem to be correctly sized and positioned now but the drawings are still off.

Comment: Problem solved. I extended the canvas to maximum jitter and drew bars within original box sizes.