# HTML canvas not drawing image

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-canvas

I have a react app but when I try to load an image is not drawing it on the canvas. Here is the code:

```
 import React , {useRef, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import image from '../assets/tesis/1_cuarto.JPG';
import imageBed from '../assets/tesis/1_cama.PNG';

export default function Canvas(props) {
  
  
  
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  //const [bed, setBed] = useState(new Image());

  useEffect(() => {


    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let bed = new Image();
    bed.src = imageBed;
    //Our first draw
    //context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height)
    bed.onload = () => {
      console.log(bed)
      context.drawImage(bed, 0, 0);
    };


  }, []);

  return (
      <canvas id="canvas" /*style={{height: '100%', width:'100%', position: 'absolute', backgroundImage: `url(${image})` , backgroundPosition: 'center', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', backgroundSize:'cover'}}*/ ref={canvasRef} />
  );
}
```

When I check the console the path points me to the image and it load, but the canvas is not drawing it.

Here is the console

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just added images of the console and yes, I was able to draw the rectangle on the callback of the onload

Comment: You were absolutely right, it was getting cropped, thank ou so much

Comment: OK. Thanks for updating and responding. I was able to get your question re-opened and write a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of transparency in the upper left corner of your image.

- According to the [w3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-author-20120329/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element), the canvas defaults to 300 x 150, so it is probably getting cropped/clipped.
- Also, you cannot use `style`/CSS to change the dimensions of your `<canvas>` as this only stretches the image without increasing the number of drawable pixels. You have to explicitly set the `width` and `height` properties.

  Do this either directly with attributes in HTML:

  ```
  <canvas width="600" height="600">
  ```

  Or in JS:

  ```
  canvas.width = 600;
  canvas.height = 600;
  ```

  For a more dynamic, window-size dependent solution in JS, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7794470/4294399

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine in plain HTML, so probably something wrong with the ref or the image directory.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("ImgCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let bed = new Image();
bed.src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615874959474-d609969a20ed?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=580&q=80';
bed.onload = () => {
ctx.drawImage(bed, 0, 0);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="ImgCanvas" style="border: 1px solid black;" width="1000px" height="600px"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```